# Apache Spark runtime exception "Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform" despite not using or referenceing Hadoop at all

Tags: java, scala, hadoop, intellij-idea, apache-spark

I am attempting to run this simple Spark program using Scala in IntelliJ 15.
The code runs fine  until it attempts to execute the line pertaining to creating a new SparkConf object :

```
import org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD
import org.apache.spark.{SparkContext, SparkConf}

object  Driver {
  //val sparkMaster:String = "spark://local:7077"
  val sparkMaster:String = "local"
  val csvPath:String = "/Users/mbrown/src/data/csv/titanic/test.csv"
  def main(args:Array[String]):Unit={
    println("Running within Driver.main().....")
    val logFile:String = "log.txt"
    val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("Testing DFrame joins...").setMaster(sparkMaster)
    val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
    val csvFileRDD = sc.textFile(csvPath).cache()
    val numAs:RDD[String] = csvFileRDD.filter(x => x.contains("a"))
    val numBs:RDD[String] = csvFileRDD.filter(x => x.contains("b"))
    println("Lines with a: %s, Lines with b: %s".format(numAs, numBs))
    System.exit(0)
  }
}
```

This is my build.gradle file:
    group 'permutation'
    version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

```
apply plugin: 'groovy'
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'scala'

//sourceCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile 'org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:2.3.11'
    compile 'com.google.guava:guava:19.0'
    compile 'org.apache.spark:spark-core_2.10:1.4.1'
    compile 'org.apache.spark:spark-assembly_2.10:1.1.0'
    compile 'org.apache.spark:spark-mllib_2.10:1.4.0'
    compile 'org.apache.spark:spark-sql_2.10:1.4.1'
    compile 'org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-common:2.7.1'
    //testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.11'
}
```

Oddly enough...when I write spark code with a similar set using Spark's Java API...I do not run into this problem.

Here is my out put and error:

```
Running within Driver.main().....
Using Spark's default log4j profile: org/apache/spark/log4j-defaults.properties
16/01/23 17:06:30 INFO SparkContext: Running Spark version 1.3.0
16/01/23 17:06:31 WARN NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library        for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:    org/apache/hadoop/conf/Configuration$DeprecationDelta
    at    org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.util.ConfigUtil.addDeprecatedKeys(ConfigUtil.java:54)
```

Any ideas ?

Comment: There seems the be some issue in your environment. The dependencies shown are `spark-core_2.10:1.4.1` but console shows `INFO SparkContext: Running Spark version 1.3.0`. Seems like your cluster and code are being compiled and executed with 2 different versions of Spark

Comment: I think you are right.   I deleted the project and recreated it.  It now works.  I have no idea what happened.  The settings int the previous config are exactly the same.  Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

So...apparently as user "Sumit" suggested...there was something awry in my enviroment.....

I delted and recreated the project all day with no luck, and then arrived at the emphiphany that it might be that some dependencies where lingering around that should not be from other gradle projects I have on my laptop.

I deleted the ~/.gradle directory, then deleted and recreated my project again...
This time it worked.

Thanks Sumit.  I appreciate it!!!!